# Отследить активность приложения

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения, logcat

Рут есть. Нужно делать скриншоты при активности определенного приложения. Перелопачивать все логи нон-стоп - слишком энергозатратно.

Как заставить logcat выдавать events только определенных приложений? Пробовал "logcat -b events MyApp:I *:S" - ничего не выдает. Или как еще можно отследить активность приложения?

Answer (score 1):

А тут смотрели ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13931729/filtering-logcat-logs-on-commandline

Comment: @Vladislav  Romarov, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: Там ничего путевого не нашел. Мне нужно отслеживать create_activity, start_activity, pause_activity, resume_activity, destroy_activity определенных приложений. То есть, я так понимаю, мне надо читать events? logcat -b events | find "myapp" - все равно выводит весь мусор.